# Searching a string from a specified start point in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am interested in searching a string (using objective-c) starting from a specific character in the middle of the string.  I could split the string, but is there another way? I don't see an obvious option for that in the definition of NSString.  I want to be able to search either backwards or forwards in the string starting from a defined character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`-[NSString rangeOfString:options:range:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_options_range_).  Use the `range` parameter to tell the string to only look in a sub-portion of the original string for the search string.